# How do I use SparkSQL and its execution engine to query Hive databases and tables without invoking any part of the Hive execution engine?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, spark-thriftserver

I've created select and join statements that I can run from the Hive CLI and/or the beeline CLI and/or Spark (2.3.1) WITH `enableHiveSupport=TRUE`. (Note: I'm using SparkR for my API)

The join and write using beeline takes 30 minutes, but the join and write using Spark with `enableHiveSupport=TRUE` takes 3.5 HOURS. This either means Spark and its connectors are crap, or I'm not using spark the way I should be... and everything I read about Spark's 'best thing since sliced bread' commentary means I'm probably not using it right.

I want to read from Hive tables, but I don't want Hive to do anything. I'd like to run joins over monthly data, run a regression on each record's monthly delta, then output my final slopes/betas to an output table in parquet that is readable from Hive, if necessary... preferably partitioned the same way that I have partitioned the tables I'm using as input data from Hive.

Here's some code, as requested... but I dont think you're going to learn anything. You're not going to get reproducible results with Big Data queries.

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client")
sessionInfo()
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.stop()
Sys.setenv(SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master yarn sparkr-shell") #--master yarn-client sparkr-shell
Sys.setenv(LOCAL_DIRS="/tmp")
config = list()
config$spark.cores.max <- 144L
config$spark.executor.cores <- 2L
config$spark.executor.memory <- '8g'
config$spark.driver.cores <- 6L
config$spark.driver.maxResultSize <-"0"
config$spark.driver.memory <- "32g"
config$spark.shuffle.service.enabled<-TRUE
config$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <-FALSE
config$spark.scheduler.mode <- 'FIFO'
config$spark.ui.port<-4044L
sparkR.session(master = "yarn",
           sparkHome = Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
           sparkConfig = config,
           enableHiveSupport = TRUE)
print("Connected!")

############ SET HIVE CONFIG 
collect(sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition") )
sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true")
collect(sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode"))
sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
##
start_time <- Sys.time()
############### READ IN DATA {FROM HIVE} 
sql('use historicdata')
data_tables<-collect(sql('show tables'))
exporttabs <- grep(pattern = 'export_historic_archive_records',x = data_tables$tableName,value = TRUE)
jointabs<-sort(exporttabs)[length(exporttabs)-(nMonths-1):0]
currenttab<-jointabs[6]

############### CREATE TABLE AND INSERT SCRIPTS 
sql(paste0('use ',hivedb))
sql(paste0('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS histdata_regression',tab_suffix))
sSelect<-paste0("Insert Into TABLE histdata_regression",tab_suffix," partition (scf) SELECT a.idkey01, a.ssn7")
sCreateQuery<-paste0("CREATE TABLE histdata_regression",tab_suffix," (idkey01 string, ssn7 string")
sFrom<-paste0("FROM historicdata.",jointabs[nMonths]," a")
sAlias<-letters[nMonths:1]
DT <- gsub(pattern = "export_historic_archive_records_",replacement = "",jointabs)
DT<-paste0(DT)
for (i in nMonths:1) {
  sSelect<-paste0(sSelect,", ",sAlias[i],".",hdAttr," as ",hdAttr,"_",i,", ",sAlias[i],".recordid as recordid_",DT[i])
  sCreateQuery<-paste0(sCreateQuery,", ",hdAttr,"_",i," int, recordid_",DT[i]," int")
  if (i==1) sCreateQuery<-paste0(sCreateQuery,') PARTITIONED BY (scf string) STORED AS ORC')
  if (i==1) sSelect<-paste0(sSelect,", a.scf")
  if (i!=nMonths) sFrom<-paste0(sFrom," inner join historicdata.",jointabs[i]," ",sAlias[i]," on ",
                              paste(paste0(paste0("a.",c("scf","idkey01","ssn7")),"=",
                                     paste0(sAlias[i],".",c("scf","idkey01","ssn7"))),collapse=" AND "))
}

system(paste0('beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://myserver1.com,myserver2.com,myserver3.com,myserver4.com,myserver5.com/work;\
            serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2" -e "',sCreateQuery,'"'))

system(paste0("beeline -u \"jdbc:hive2://myserver1.com,myserver2.com,myserver3.com,myserver4.com,myserver5.com/work;\
            serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2\" -e \"",sSelect," ",sFrom,"\""))
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please share only **relevant** code. That is, only the query that takes too long to execute. Also, add the spark plan for that query. This is not for reproduction, but for investigation.